# Angular 6 and Firebase (database) rule configuration

Tags: angular, firebase, angular6

I'm using firebase (database) for data reading and writing data. Meanwhile, the rule section of the database was set to public, but now I have set it to private and now my app can't access the database without the uid that I have declared in the .read and .write section. What changes do I have to do in order to get it working again with private access? I have tried adding `uid: "acdsds"`, in firebase initializeApp config in app.module.ts but nothing is happening I'm still getting the

> permission_denied (ERR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No changes were required in the angular app as i was already using Firebase authentication. I just copy pasted the admin uid to the rules and the problem was solved, this link was quite helpful

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart